# How to Split Country and Year part separately, Folder creation is not working properly in ADLS I can't find From Where is the Bug Raised

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I was Supposed to give folder structure for file is /yyyy/MM/dd But it is coming like yyyy/MM/dd and the pipeline Structure is like
[image]

[image]

[image]
and the result I am getting like below

[image]

Comment: Is it partially correct? Because I can see the folder CA and FR do not have year in that?

Comment: Whether AU,CA,DE,FR are values from `JobName` parameter?

Comment: yes it got resolved Actually I checked Under Monitor Previous PL is running and overlapping the results  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@concat('originalData/SFMC/CampaignLevelData/',pipeline().parameters.jobName,'/',variables('YMD'),'/',variables('MM'),'/',variables('Day'),'/')
```

There is no error in the expression and I tried the same in my environment and Folder structure is `....AU/2023/02/17`

[image]

[image]

Error could be in value of variables('YMD'). Check the input data from your end.